# How to read a property from a JSON response when the HTTP response has a failure code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jqxhr

I have this code:

```
$.post(Routing.generate('parMarcaModelo'), {
    "marcaId": currBranch,
    "modeloId": currModel,
    "marcaNombre": currBranchName,
    "modeloNombre": currModelName
}, 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // do something here
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Catch error from server and logs to console
    var err = eval("(" + jqXHR.responseText + ")");
    colose.log('Error', err.Message, 20000);

    return false;
});
```

The server side returns a JSON like this one:

```
{
   "success":false,
   "error":"El par Marca2-Modelo1 ya existe. Por favor escoja otra combinaci\u00f3n.",
}
```

But also returns a 400 code so Ajax call will go through `.fail()` callback insted of `.done()`. Having this information, how I can catch the `error` key from the JSON in the `.fail()` to show to users?

I have found this code:

```
$.get('http://localhost/api').then(function(res) {
    var filter $.Deferred()

    if (res.success) {
        filter.resolve(res.data)
    } else {
        filter.reject(res.error)
    }

    return filter.promise()
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log('Name:',  data.name) // Outputs: Foo
}).fail(function(error) {
    console.log('Error:', error) // Outputs: Something bad happened.
})
```

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265814/how-to-trigger-jquery-ajax-error-callback-based-on-server-response-in-my-case) topic at SO but does not know if is right and also if will affect my code in someway.

Any help or advice?

Comment: If you get JSON you are in done() method

Comment: If the message is at `err.error`, why are you accessing `err.Message` instead? And why are you using `eval()` to parse your JSON?

Comment: ...and what do you mean by "catch" the `error` key? Are you throwing an error, or was this just an unfortunate use of the word `catch`, which has very specific meaning?

Comment: @squint I get that code from somewhere and is untested is just curious to me how it should work in order to modify and fit to my environment, should be `err.error` as you say? And for the `catch` I mean when any fails on the server side I send a `400` response to the Ajax request and also sends as a Json the generic message for the application, but I'm pretty sure that will be errors from the Ajax,jQuery, jqXHR side, I'm right? I need to catch all of them, the ones from JSON coming from 400 response and the ones from jqXHR, why?

Comment: If I understand correctly, a clearer title might be something like "How to read a property from a JSON response when the HTTP response has a failure code?"

Comment: @apsillers have sense, modifying right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending in `'json'` as the success callback function to `$.post()`.

This is the correct function signature: 
`jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`

---

**Clarification**

This code will work, since it passes in an empty function in place of the 'success'.

```
$.post('rest.php', {data : 'data'}, function(){},'json').done(
function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // do something here
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Catch error from server and logs to console
    console.log('Error', jqXHR.responseJSON, 20000);

    return false;
});
```

However, this code will not:

```
$.post('rest.php', {data : 'data'}, 'json').done(
function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // do something here
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Catch error from server and logs to console
    console.log('Error', jqXHR.responseJSON, 20000);

    return false;
});
```

For proof, look at line 781-798 in the [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js). If the `data` parameter is a function, e.g. the `success` callback, the items will get shifted. However, since this is not the case, every parameter will be put in by the position they appear in the function.

In the second version, `Ajax.succees` will be set to the string `'json'` and the `Ajax.dataType` is set to `undefined`. The `jqXHR.responseJSON` of that version will return a `undefined`, since it's not parsed as JSON.

The first version, however, returns a JSON object.

---

Also, you wrote `colose.log` instead of `console.log` in your code. That might be why couldn't get the data.

Comment: `[, ...]` means optional.

Comment: `return false;` is useless

Comment: So this is the way I should go? @epascarello why? because the callback goes through `.fail()` and it's a fail itself?

Comment: Why? because you can not return from an asynchronous method.

Comment: @epascarello didn't know that one

Comment: bvx89: You're just not understanding. Your clarification with the empty function is completely unnecessary because those arguments ***are optional***. Any one (or all) of the optional arguments can be excluded. Nothing needs to be put in its place.

Comment: @squint I edited my answer with the source code to explain what I meant. 

Others: I'd rather use the `$ajax` function in jQuery to create this functionality in a cleaner way, but I was trying not to alter the original code too much. That's why I didn't remove the `return false;` as well, which I know is useless.