# Can we fail $ ajax call, even if the response is valid 200OK

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, json-schema-validator

Often there are situations where the server responses are 200OK, but the response content is not the expected one.
Can we trigger the jquery ajax error callback, even if the response is success, based on some criteria in the response?

The response, in my case is a valid json, but not the expected response (schema validation failed), so not a json parsing error.

I'm looking forward to a solution, where the response is evaluated before it actually hits the success or error callbacks.

Comment: Why not refactor the code in the error callback into a more general error handling routine, and call it from both places?

Comment: why? That makes no sense

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6265911/916000

Comment: If your error call back is a separate function, then you could call it within your success call back based on the condition. Though as above responses suggest, that isn't a good practice.

Comment: right, what is the good practice?

Comment: Just validate the schema from within the success callback and take appropriate action from there.

Comment: That's something I don't want to do. As I mentioned, the response should be evaluated before it actually hits the success or error callbacks.

Comment: Its called contract driven development, useful while communicating with external microservices.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need fail ajax? The error callback should use handle unknow exceptions.
If you want to know the server process result, just return different type message, then take different process in ajax success callback by message type.
If there is no exceptions, always process server result in success callback.

Comment: As I mentioned, The response, in my case is a valid json, but not the expected response, so not a json parsing error.

Comment: Check the marked of this question, it's what i mean.

Comment: Its called contract driven development, useful while communicating with external microservices. You're answer isn't satisfactory.