# Show the returned error from php file in jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to get data via ajax. everything works fine except the "error handler". whenever i have error in my php i want that the error is sent to the html page (javascript file). it's not working.

im using the success in my ajax.

**What i want is to get alerted with the msg and error ive set in the PHP file (line 5 and 6)**

Here is my code:

**PHP**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
$resp = array(
    'status' => "Error",
    'msg'    => "Error Msg",
    'error'  => mysqli_error($conn)
);
echo json_encode($resp);
die();
} else {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    // $ownId = $row['own_id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $geraet = $row['manuf'].' '.$row['model'];
    $fail = $row['fail'];
    $abg_dat = $row['pick_date'];
    $status = $row['status'];

    $return_arr[] = array("id" => $id,
                    "name" => $name,
                    "geraet" => $geraet,
                    "fail" => $fail,
                    "abg_dat" => $abg_dat,
                    "status" => $status
                );
}
$resp = array(
    'status' => "Succ" ,
    'msg'    => "Daten erfolgreich abgerufen",
    'resp'   => $return_arr
);

echo json_encode($resp);
}
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url: `${phpDir}/inc/techniker.inc.php`,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        if (response['status'] == "Error") {
            alert(response['status'] +  "<br/>" + response['error']);
            
        } else {
            var len = response['resp'].length;
            var rspKey = response['resp'];
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var id = rspKey[i].id;
                var name = rspKey[i].name;
                var geraet = rspKey[i].geraet;
                var stoerung = rspKey[i].fail;
                var abgabe = rspKey[i].abg_dat;
                var status = rspKey[i].status;
                // example on muliple rows
                // var username = response[i].username;
                
                var tr_str = `
                <tr id="${id}" onclick="tabCaller(${id})">
                    <td>#${id}</td>
                    <td>${name}</td>
                    <td>${geraet}</td>
                    <td>${stoerung}</td>
                    <td>${abgabe}</td>
                    <td>${status}</td>
                </tr>
                `;
                $("#techniker_tbody").append(tr_str);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
when mysqli error is happening the php is breaking and showing the error before he sends the response. that why im not gettin the 'error' either the 'msg'

Comment: error: function(e) { alert(e); }  after success function

Comment: i want to display the msg sented by PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = JSON.parse(response);
if(arr["status"] == "Error"){
alert(arr["error"]);
}
```

Comment: where to put that? inside the if statment in the success?

Comment: inside function (response){

Comment: inside -> success: function(response){  ?

Comment: it's not working. im not getting anything displayed since no success and im having error

Comment: first you check by alert(response) and see if error is actually being returned by php script if no then we can check the php script.

Answer (score 0):

What @aryan said was right. You can refer to the following which explains it well. [How to trigger jquery.ajax() error callback based on server response, not HTTP 500?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265814/how-to-trigger-jquery-ajax-error-callback-based-on-server-response-not-http-5)

When your "webservice" is returning a HTTP Statuscode 400, 401, 403, 405 or 5XX jQuery ajax event error will be triggered.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: `${phpDir}/inc/techniker.inc.php`,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        ...
    },
    error: function(error) {
       // alert, append to body
    }
});
```

Just make sure to send a http header with the response. The mysql error is resulting in a HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error).

Like so:

```
header_status(500);
...
```

Comment: refferring to the php code i wrote above. what should i write inside the error: ... ?

Comment: also the status im getting is 200. not sure why. the error is that there are no such a table. the error is written for a test purpose.

Comment: Since the mysql error will be parsed in the body. You can use 
error: function(error) {
    alert(error['responseText']); // here is the body
}
...

Comment: Can you try console outputting error with console.log(error). What is the output?